# Javascript muito lento no safari mobile

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari

Na minha aplicação tem um siples javascript para incrementar um campo, o problema que no safari fica ultra lerdo quase não funciona, enquanto no chrome funciona perfeitamente.Existe algo a se fazer para rodar normal no safari?

js:

```
$("#aumentaDesconto").click(function () {
var input = $("#txtDesconto")[0];
var desconto = parseInt(input.value, 10) + 1;
input.value = desconto;

});
```

Comment: Poste também a função `calcularValor`.

Comment: Na verdade vou remover ela , pois elan ao tem nada ave com meu problema.

Comment: Está lento pra incrementar os valores no campo.

Comment: Acho difícil a culpa estar nesse código, mas de qualquer maneira tente `var desconto = +input.value + 1;`

Comment: acho que a culpa é do safari mesmo, vi varios relatos de lentesas com safari e javascript, porem preciso do mesmo rodando no safari.Vou testar seu codigo

Comment: Utilize `console.count('teste')` dentro da função e veja no seu console quantas vezes a função foi chamada. Talvez você deixou este código dentro de um loop e o evento foi vinculado várias vezes.

Answer (score 1):

A única coisa que vejo poder optimizar aqui é remover o jQuery e fazer isso com JavaScript puro. Ficaria assim:

```
document.getElementById("aumentaDesconto").addEventListener('click', function () {
    var input = document.getElementById("txtDesconto");
    var desconto = parseInt(input.value, 10) + 1;
    input.value = desconto;
});
```

Se nõ resolver o problema sugiro que coloques um jsFiddle que reproduza o problema para podermos analizar.

Comment: Fiz dessa forma e o incremento nao funcionou.

Comment: @WarLock tinha deixado um `#` a mais, corrigi agora. Coloca esse script no final do body e testa.

Answer (score 1):

Da maneira como você fez, o código executa uma busca no seu HTML pelo elemento de id `txtDesconto` toda vez que `#aumentaDesconto` é clicado.

Uma maneira de otimizar é fazer o cache dos elementos utilizados repetidamente, pois pesquisar na DOMTree é bastante custoso para o browser.

Tente assim:

```
var input_desconto = document.getElementById("txtDesconto"),
    aumenta_desconto = document.getElementById("aumentaDesconto");

aumentaDesconto.addEventListener("click", function () {
    input.value = parseInt(input_desconto.value, 10) + 1;
}, false);
```

Fiz um [<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/4y7hn1g2/).

Comment: Continua lento, testei no ipad e iphone, safari realmente nao rola...

Comment: Tem certeza que é esse script que está deixando lento?
Já tentou tirar ele e ver como a página se comporta sem o script?